# Set glPointSize to a Float in PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, 3d, pyopengl

I'm drawing a point in PyOpenGL, but I need it to be a decimal. When I use glPointSize(), it will round to the nearest int.

Is there a way to make the point size a float, and if not, what is the most efficient alternative?

```py
glColor3fv((1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
glPointSize(2.4)
glBegin(GL_POINTS)
for a in points:
    glVertex3f(a[0], a[1], 3)
# glEnd()
```

For example, if I set the point size to anything between 1.5 and 2.5, it'll just round to 2.

According to chat gpt, what I'm currently doing by setting the parameter to a float is correct, so it might be possible I'm missing something else in the program?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable [Multisampling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Multisampling#Multisampling):

```py
pygame.init()
pygame.display.gl_set_attribute(pygame.GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, True)
pygame.display.gl_set_attribute(pygame.GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, 8)
screen= pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.OPENGL)
```

and you need to enable drawing points with proper filtering

```py
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH)
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 I think you forgot to call `glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH)`